# Cannot loop the Array-like Object

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an array of object products that received from server.

`return response()->json(['products' => $products->toArray()]);`

Here is its log:

[image]

And I need to loop through it to get the `product.attributes` that I think it's a array-like object, so I use `Array.prototype.forEach.call`

```
                this.products.forEach(product => {
                    console.log(product);
                    console.log(product.attributes);

                    Array.prototype.forEach.call(product.attributes, function(child) {
                        // It seems the loop doesn't work, so nothing is printed out.
                        console.log(child);
                    });
                });
```

But it seems the loop on array-like object didn't work, so nothing was printed out, even my `product.attributes` wasn't empty. Here is `product.attributes` log:

[image]

Comment: What is this `->` notation? Doesn't look like javascript?

Comment: that's from Laravel

Comment: Object.keys [MDN, spec] — A function providing an array of the names of an object's own, enumerable properties whose names are strings.
Object.values [MDN, spec] — A function providing an array of the values of an object's own, enumerable properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`products.attributes` is not an array like object, it is object.

But you can still iterate to that if you want. You just need to:

```
Object.entries(product.attribues).forEach(([key, value]) => {  })
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `product.attributes` is also an Object. So `Array.prototype.forEach.call` doesn't work.

Try [for...in statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in):

```
for (var key in product.attributes) {
  console.log(product.attributes[key]);
}
```

Comment: Don't put url as an answer,because website contains may change in future so try to answer by reading website and mention that website as a reference.

Comment: @Lakmi thanks for reminding me. Edited my answer